# smarty , how to solve smarty incompatible

Tags: smarty

> unrecognized tag: `$ncache['tab']="gallery_cat"` (Smarty_Compiler.class.php, line 455)

i got this error, when i type the following code

```
{$ncache[tab]="gallery_cat"}
{$ncache.tab="gallery_cat"}
```

anyway to assign an array in smarty?

Answer (score 0):

You can assign arrays in smarty with the php tag like this:

```
{php}
$this->assign("array", array('1','2','3'));
{/php}
```

Or if you are using version 3 you can also use it directly from smarty

```
{$array = ['1','2','3']}
```

Comment: {$ncache[tab]="gallery_cat"} do we hav any short hand like this??